# Pandas agg function different behaviours depending on call definition

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I don't understand the `agg` behaviour. See examples below and expected result.

```
pd.DataFrame({'d': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]}).agg(list)
Out[372]: 
          d
0  {'a': 1}
1  {'b': 2}
pd.DataFrame({'d': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]}).agg(lambda col: list(col))
Out[373]: 
          d
0  {'a': 1}
1  {'b': 2}
pd.DataFrame({'d': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]}).agg({'d': list})
Out[374]: 
     d
0  [a]
1  [b]
pd.DataFrame({'d': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]}).agg({'d': lambda col: list(col)})
Out[375]: 
     d
0  [a]
1  [b]
```

Expected result is:

```
pd.DataFrame({'d': [list(pd.DataFrame({'d': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]}).d)]})
Out[379]: 
                      d
0  [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
```

Comment: No your expectation from the agg is wrong. when you convert dictionary to list, it returns just key not a key value pair. for example `d = {'name 1':'thasin', 'name 2': 'mohamed'}` `print(list(d))` this returns `['name 1', 'name 2']` not `[{'name 1':'thasin', 'name 2': 'mohamed'}]`

Comment: The documentation says "Aggregate using one or more operations over the specified axis" so I am expecting the function passed in `agg` is applied to each series, and so the expected result

Comment: yeah documentation is right, but `converting dictionary to list will return just key`. please take a close look at provided example.

Answer (score 0):

You might need another `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]})
>>> pd.DataFrame([df.values], columns=df.columns)
                          d
0  [[{'a': 1}], [{'b': 2}]]
>>>
```

`agg` isn't able to do that, it aggregates and does X operation on Y column, it doesn't "aggregate" values...

For your other example, I would do:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: [df[x.name].values])).T.apply(lambda x: x.str[0])
                      d                     e
0  [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]  [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
>>>
```